# Laravel multiple where condition in whereHas callback

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am creating a general search function with Laravel 5.2 and I want to display all the books in which occurs the searched keyword in: the book's title, book's subject, book's plot, book's author name, book's author surname;
I thought that this code would work:

```
$results = Book::whereHas('author', function ($query) use ($keyword)
                     {
                          $query->where('surname', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                               ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
                     })
                     ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                     ->orWhere('plot', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                     ->orWhere('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                     ->get();
```

But when I use as a keyword the name of an author, I get as a results the whole library.
Instead if I enter the surname of an author it works perfectly.

I found out this solution, that is not optimal in my opinion, but at least it works:

```
$results = Book::whereHas('author', function ($query) use ($keyword)
                     {
                          $query->where('surname', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
                     })
                     ->orWhereHas('author', function ($query) use ($keyword)
                     {
                          $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
                     })
                     ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                     ->orWhere('plot', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                     ->orWhere('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                     ->get();
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe create some additional index table for the search (keywords)? If you want "some" speed use redis instead of mysql.

Comment: @Hardy Thanks for the suggestion, but actually is just a project for school; since I found out this interesting behavior of laravel, I wanted to know the reasons, nothing more than that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that the where clauses added in your closure aren't the only where clauses being applied to the subquery. The `whereHas()` method generates a subquery that starts with a where clause on the ids for the relationship. Because of this, your subquery isn't just `where x or y`, it is actually `where x and y or z`.

Given this set of where clauses, and the order of operations for logical operators, if the `z` condition is true (your 'name' condition), the whole where clause will return true, meaning the constraint on only looking at related objects is completely ignored. Since the constraint on related objects is ignored, the `has` condition will be true for every record (if 'name' matches any record).

Below is an example of your logical conditions:

```
// first boolean is the related keys check
// second boolean is the surname check
// third boolean is the name check

// this is your current logic
// as you can see, this returns true even when looking at an
// author not even related to the book.
var_export(false && false || true); // true

// this is what your logic needs to be
var_export(false && (false || true)); // false
```

So, to solve this issue, you need to wrap your `or` conditions in parentheses, so they're evaluated as you intended. You can do this by passing a closure to the `where()` method, and then any conditions added inside the closure will be inside parentheses:

```
$results = Book::whereHas('author', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
        $query->where(function ($q) use ($keyword) {
            $q->where('surname', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
        });
    })
    ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->orWhere('plot', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->orWhere('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clever answer, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score -2):

have you tried creating a local query scope for your author/user model such as named() then applying that

```
public function scopeNamed($query)
{
    return $query->where('surname', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                 ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
}
```

Then your query

```
$results = Book::whereHas('author', function ($query) use ($keyword)
                 {
                      $query->named();
                 })
                 ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                 ->orWhere('plot', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                 ->orWhere('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                 ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: I imagine it was because, even though this answer is useful for showing how to create a scope, it doesn't do anything to solve the issue. The original code and the code in this answer are functionally equivalent. You've only just moved where the `where` clauses are defined.